# Finding formula for 3 points

Tags: trigonometry

I have $3$ points ($x+y$ coordinates) according to the graphics below. I would need to understand how i can find the formula to calculate the $Y$ value with any given X value. 
A few additional information that should make it solvable:

1. $P_1 ≠ P_2 ≠ P_3$
2. the only known value besides the 3 points is the value 1000 in the graphics below.

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly; you want a function of the for $A\cos(\omega t + \phi)$ that hits those three points all within the first quarter cycle?

Comment: StrafeAe , yep that right, so with any new given X number, i can get the proper Y number... @viktor: the situation is this: i have a camera with a 90° field of view (45° to the left and 45° to the right) in the photo there is a rectangular object, that varies in distance, but always stays centered in the picture. the max distance is 1.5 meters, the min. distance is 0.8 meters. the X is the distance from the object to the ground (1500- dist to camera) and the Y values are the distance from the left border of the picture, to where this object begins.

Comment: @StrafeAe actually I would not need the formula, I would need to understand how to find the formula.. so once i have the correct points i can do it myself...

Comment: you are right, i had wrong data posted. I updated the post with all information since I do belive that there are other errors on my side. I drew what i actually need as it might be easier to understand and without errors. thank you and sorry

Comment: For me it would also be OK to get the 1000-Y... would be ok.. As far as i understand the fucntion should be logarithmic..